# Yii2 Reset password from phpmyadmin

Tags: yii2

I got a Yii application, and one of the users forgot their password, and I do not have a reset password option on the app, but I have access to the Database through PHPMyAdmin, the table is called userlogin, and I have fields :

ID
username
password
spice

the spice field contain a hashed string,
So when I try to reset the password, entered the password and select MD5 in the function dropdown, then click Go,

But when I try to login, I still have an invalid password.

Any Idea? please help.

Comment: You can create new hash using YII function then replace your older password in databases. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-passwords

Comment: Yii does not use md5 for hashing passwords. You should be able to generate hash by using any online bcrypt password hash generator (although you should change it after you log in).